# Cannot add task 'myTask' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have 'mytask' in myPlugin that is used in another project. While building the project I get this error from module1.

```
Build file 'OtherProject/modules/module1/build.gradle' line: 2
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':modules:myModule1'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'myPlugin'.
   > Cannot add task 'myTask' as a task with that name already exists.
```

To fix this I set, `overwrite: true` in myTask creation in **InternalModuleFeature.groovy**

```
project.tasks.create(
    name: 'myTask',
    overwrite: true,
    ...
)
```

This worked fine until I Upgraded to **Gradle 7.0**. Now I get this error in module2

```
Build file 'OtherProject/modules/module2/build.gradle' line: 11    
* What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':modules:module2'.
    > Failed to apply plugin 'myPlugin'.
       > Could not create task ':modules:module2:myTask'.
          > Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported.  Use create() or register() directly instead.  You attempted to replace a task named 'myTask', but there is no existing task with that name.
```

I have tried adding null check before creating task - Still the same error.

How do I resolve this?

**Going back to older version of Gradle is not an option.**

Comment: not sure if this is useful to you, but there is also `maybeCreate` it only creates the task if it does not yet exist.

Comment: any solution .. I have almost same error 
Replacing an existing task that may have already been used by other plugins is not supported.